# MVC 5 - Would like to have page display if not logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the following code to display a login form (Login.cshtml) when the user is not authenticated and the main page when the user is authenticated:
Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- META SECTION -->
    <title>Coalesce</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- END META SECTION -->
    <!-- CSS INCLUDE -->
    <link href="~/Content/Template/css/theme-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- EOF CSS INCLUDE -->
</head>
<body>
     @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            <div class="login-container">
                @RenderPage("~/views/Account/Login.cshtml")
            </div>
            RenderBody();
        }
        else {
                ...Normal page here
}
</body>
</html>
```

The Login.cshtml looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
     ...Login controls
</body>
</html>
```

I am using OWIN and everything wroks fine, but when I hit the login page portion, it only displays on half the screen, so half is the login page, and the bottom is white.

I've tried RenderPartial and a few other things in the authentication check, but I get get the login page to display on the full browser window.
I'm sure its the way that 
         @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                
                    @RenderPage("~/views/Account/Login.cshtml")
                
                RenderBody();
            }
is constructed, but i'm currently stumped.

Comment: you are rendering the Body when the user isn't authenticated

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this approach before, but in any case (assuming it works) Login.cshtml should not contain `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>` and `<body>` tags because it will be rendered inside Layout.cshtml, which already contains these tags.

The approach that I am familiar with is: let a Controller, or even a global ActionFilter, check if one is logged in. If not, show `View("Login")`, or redirect to `/Home/Login`. Then let Login.cshtml be rendered using Layout.cshtml (which contains no login logic) - and not the other way around which is what you seem to be trying.

**Controllers/HomeController.cs** example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        return View("Login");
    // Add normal flow here
}
```

Comment: agree, one suggestion, use the standard (or custom if need be) AuthorizeAttribute(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) on controllers instead of using checks on authentication inside controller actions.

Comment: I have the Authorize attribute above the Index method in the controller and the suggested changes, but now it displays BOTH the login page and the authorized content